# How to run a bean as a background service?

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-7, jboss-eap-6

I need to be able to initiate a bean at startup and have it run constantly in the background using some kind of internal event/time loop (looking for data records to process). I was wondering what the correct Java EE 7/ JBoss EAP 6.2 method of doing this would be.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by constantly running in the background? You could use timers or singleton scheduled EJB. Also FWIW JBoss EAP 6.x is Java EE 6. If you want Java EE 7 have a look at WildFly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Quartz Scheduler framework and have the job fire up as configured.

Comment: It looks promising, thank you. Do you know if there will be any complications with a never ending job i.e. timeouts?

Comment: I haven't worked on never ending jobs , but it seems Quartz does handle this with additional configuration, you can find more details at: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks like great info.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve. There are various ways you can achieve the stated goal. Some i can think of are :-

1)Use spring which automatically instantiate singleton beans on startup and call init method while start up

2)In terms of web app , you can use loadOnstartUp servlet configuration

3)Use quarts Job to run the background jobs

Comment: I tried using a startup singleton but JBoss seemed to have an issue when the startup code (Which would start the loop) didn't pass back control

Answer (score 0):

EJBs should work fine in this case (standard Java EE - no external framework needed)

I am assuming you need a 'pull' mode for the data rather than having a component to 'listen' to data events

1. Spin up a Singleton EJB
2. Write your business logic which would query the data repository

   @Singleton
   @Startup //container initializes the bean when it starts or when the application is deployed
   public class MySingletonEJB{

   @Schedule //configure this annotation as per required schedule e.g. via a Cron like syntax
   public void executeJob(){
   //.... search data records
   }

   }